# Typescript Material-UI Table duplicated code issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

Sorry for such vague question title, could not think of anything better.

I'm trying to figure out Typescript implementation of [Material-UI tables](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#EnhancedTable.tsx), in particular table under "Sorting and selecting". It conveniently has a [Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ipxty?file=/demo.tsx).

So I have multiple pages with tables. If I just copy paste this code as is (with data and style adjustments of course), there is a lot of duplicated code happening. I've managed to fix most of it, but I struggle with `EnhancedTableProps` and `EnhancedTableHead`.

I can't achieve that, because they use `Data` interface, which is different for every table. So Data has to stay for every table and can't be unified.

I can't think of a proper solution, mostly because I'm very new to Typescript.

```
interface EnhancedTableProps {
  classes: ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;
  numSelected: number;
  onRequestSort: (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, property: keyof Data) => void;
  onSelectAllClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  order: Order;
  orderBy: string;
  rowCount: number;
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
  const { classes, onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property: keyof Data) => (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'select all desserts' }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'normal'}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === 'desc' ? 'sorted descending' : 'sorted ascending'}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I had to change.

```
interface HeadCell<Data> {
  ...
}

interface EnhancedTableProps<Data> {
  ...
  headCells: HeadCell<Data>[];
}

function EnhancedTableHead<Data>(props: EnhancedTableProps<Data>) {
  const { classes, onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort, headCells } = props;
}


            <EnhancedTableHead
              ...
              headCells={headCells}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `Data` generic

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase/#generic-components

```js
interface EnhancedTableProps<Data> {
  // ...
  onRequestSort: (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, property: keyof Data) => void;
}

function EnhancedTableHead<Data>(props: EnhancedTableProps<Data>) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: this is a very basic answer without any integrity. I knew, that generics are the way, but couldn't figure the details.